# Laravel: Unificar consulta Eloquent (Today, Month & Year)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, querybuilder

De nuevo por acá con esta duda: Tengo muchas consultas que debo repetir el código ya que dependen de la elección de un filtro obtenido a través de un Select (Today, Month & Year), el cual muestra la información correspondiente en los rangos antes especificados: Día Actual, Mes Actual y Año Actual.

Acá el código:

```
    if ($filterDashboardMerchant == 'month'){
        // Total Revenue || Month
        $totalRevenue = AffiliateOrder::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.id', '=', 'affiliates_orders.affiliate_id')
            ->whereMonth('order_date', Carbon::now()->month)
            ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as orders_total'))
            ->where('affiliates.merchant_id', $merchant->merchant_id)
            ->get();
        }
    else{
        if($filterDashboardMerchant == 'year'){
            // Total Revenue || Year
            $totalRevenue = AffiliateOrder::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.id', '=', 'affiliates_orders.affiliate_id')
                ->whereYear('order_date', Carbon::now()->year)
                ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as orders_total'))
                ->where('affiliates.merchant_id', $merchant->merchant_id)
                ->get();
        else{
            // Total Revenue || Today
            $totalRevenue = AffiliateOrder::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.id', '=', 'affiliates_orders.affiliate_id')
                ->whereDay('order_date', Carbon::now()->day)
                ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as orders_total'))
                ->where('affiliates.merchant_id', $merchant->merchant_id)
                ->get();
        }
    }
```

En vista que todo el código de la consulta es igual y sólo 3 de las condiciones son diferentes dentro de las mismas:

```
->whereMonth('order_date', Carbon::now()->month)

->whereYear('order_date', Carbon::now()->year)

->whereDay('order_date', Carbon::now()->day)
```

Como podría cambiar solo esa condición en el mismo fragmento de código, dependiente de la elección en el Select que filtra a las mismas???

Me sería de gran ayuda, pues esto es apenas menos del 5% de lo que tengo desarrollado y me ahorraria mucho código.

Gracias...

Answer (score 0):

No he probado la consulta, pero se me ocurre lo siguiente:

**Parte 1**

Mueve el cuerpo de la consulta al Modelo `AffiliateOrder` como un *localScope* de esta forma:

```
public function scopeFilterByDate($query, $date)
    {
        return $query->join('affiliates', 'affiliates.id', '=', 'affiliates_orders.affiliate_id')
                ->whereDate('order_date', Carbon::now()->$date)
                ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as orders_total'))
                ->where('affiliates.merchant_id', $merchant->merchant_id);
    }
```

La cual recibirá 2 parámetros:

- La `$query` para la consulta interna
- La variable `$date` que nos permitirá cuando invoquemos dicha consulta pasar de forma dinámica si es: dia, mes o año

**Parte 2**

Ahora dentro de tu constrolador asignamos en 3 variables los posibles valores de tiempo por los cuales el usuario podrá filtrar:

```
$dia = now()->day;
$mes = now()->month;
$anio = now()->year;
```

**Parte 3**

Podemos dejar la sintaxis de `if/else` y tal vez irnos por la estructura que nos ofrece el método `when` para verificar *cuando* una condición sea cierta; además podemos hacer uso de las *arrow functions* que existen desde PHP 7.4 para acortar mas el código:

```
AffiliateOrder::query()->when($eleccion === "month", 
                            fn($query) => $query::filterByDate($mes)
                        )->when($eleccion === "day", 
                            fn($query) => $query::filterByDate($dia)
                        )->when($eleccion === "year", 
                            fn($query) => $query::filterByDate($anio)
                        )->get();
```

Si no con la estructura `if/else` regular pudiera verse asi

```
if($eleccion === "month")
{
    return AffiliateOrder::filterByDate($mes)->get();
} else if($eleccion === "day")
{
    return AffiliateOrder::filterByDate($dia)->get();
} else {
    return AffiliateOrder::filterByDate($anio)->get();
}
```

Comment: Se ve viable pero si muevo la consulta a scopeFilterByDate con whereYear no devuelve la información requerida. Lo cambié a where y tampoco...

Comment: Hola @BetaM. Aun no me funciona... hice todo lo que me comentas y me da un error: syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN) en esta línea: fn($query) => return $query::filterByDate($mes)... le coloque ; al final a ver pero aun nada que funciona

Comment: Ya encontré la solución, pero no sé si este bien en cuanto a buenas prácticas, la coloque en una respuesta para que visualices mejor el código @BetaM.

Comment: Ninguno de los dos me funcionó. La que modificaste con el whereDate devuelve null y la de if/else da error el return... Ah y eso que hice es en el controlador. Igual estoy repitiendo mucho código pues uso el mismo condicional para unas 10 consultas que debo hacer entre esos rangos de dia actual, mes actual y año actual.

Answer (score 0):

La solución que conseguí fue esta:

```
    $query = AffiliateOrder::join('affiliates', 'affiliates.id', '=', 'affiliates_orders.affiliate_id')
        ->select(DB::raw('sum(total) as orders_total'))
        ->where('affiliates.merchant_id', $merchant->merchant_id);
        if($filterDashboardMerchant === 'month')
        {
            $query->whereMonth('order_date', Carbon::now()->month);
        } 
        else if($filterDashboardMerchant === 'year')
        {
            $query->whereYear('order_date', Carbon::now()->year);
        }
        else
        {
            $query->whereDay('order_date', Carbon::now()->day);
        }
    $totalRevenue = $query->get();
```